# Performance of UNION versus UNION ALL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, union, union-all

I have to run a SELECT statement across several tables. I am sure the tables return different records. I am anyway using UNION ALL.

Is it better to use UNION or of UNION ALL in performance terms  when I am sure the tables return different records?

Comment: possible duplicate of [To union or union all, that is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909563/to-union-or-union-all-that-is-the-question)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

UNION ALL will perform better than UNION when you're not concerned about eliminating duplicate records because you're avoiding an expensive [distinct sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177486.aspx) operation. See: [SQL SERVER – Difference Between Union vs. Union All – Optimal Performance Comparison](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/)

Answer (score 5):

UNION ALL always is faster, because UNION exclude duplicated entries

Comment: It's not "always" faster. I'm doing some performance tweaking right now and finding UNION almost twice as fast as UNION ALL even though the resulting query returns the exact same set of results. This is MS SQL Server. I can't explain it and was hoping someone else could.

Comment: @PeterMoore Did you also have no duplicates like me? I also cannot see any speed difference between the two when checking it without any tools just on a 10s query, but there is also no reason not to believe that `union all` must be faster for large tables aso. Perhaps something that gets important only if there *are* cases that make `union` and `union all` return different results = if you have duplicates. Makes no sense, I know.

Comment: I have the same problem as @EmperorEto: the same MS SQL query with the same number of unique rows in each, the only difference is `UNION` vs `UNION ALL`. The `UNION` version takes 6-8 seconds to execute. The `UNION ALL` version takes 30-90 seconds to execute. The union is used in the FROM clause of a PIVOT.

Comment: @Vijchti since this comment I have come to realize both UNION and UNION ALL must be avoided like the plague in MS SQL. I don't know enough about db engines to say definitively there's a bug, but I have seen too many instances of both these operators completely breaking what should be extremely efficient queries that I consider them unusable. Fortunately there are usually ways around using either.

Answer (score 4):

UNION implement internally two queries.
1.`SELECT` which will return a dataset
2.`DISTINCT`. 
Anyone who has studied database internals can easily understand that a `DISTINCT` clause is extremely costly in terms of processing.

If you are pretty sure that the resultant dataset need not have unique rows then we can skip `UNION` and use `UNION ALL` instead.

`UNION ALL` will be same as `UNION` except that it doesn't fire a `DISTINCT` internally sparing us costly operations

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use UNION ALL when you know you want all the result rows, whether or not you know they'll be distinct or not. UNION without "all" will *always* perform the "distinct check", regardless of what the data actually is.

Answer (score 3):

Why is UNION ALL faster? Because UNION must do a sort to remove the duplicates. If you do not need to remove duplicates then UNION ALL is the better option, however UNION does have a purpose and should be used when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that it depends on your data.

If performance is measured end-to-end (from the moment the client sends the first byte of the request to the moment it gets the last byte of the response) then you have the following two extremes:

1. The vast minority (say 1%) of the result set contains duplicates
2. The vast majority (say 99%) of the result set contains duplicates

In case 1, UNION ALL will be faster simply because it does not need to sort the data (to remove duplicates) before returning it.

In case 2, UNION will be faster because it's much quicker to remove duplicates in memory than sending them over the wire. If your result set contains 1 million rows with only 2 unique values then your network time will be much smaller once those duplicates have been removed.