# Random Sample in Groups

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a code where I need to pull 400 random employees from this list of over 60,000. THere are 8 different job groupings, I need a certain number of each from each grouping. So of the total 400 random samples I need that 400 needs to consist of specific numbers from each of the 8 groups. This is the code so far:

```
SELECT TOP (400) Business_Unit, GEMSID, First_Name, Last_Name, Region, District, Job_Function,     Email_Address, Job_Group_Code
FROM  dbo.v_TMS_employee_HR
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

IE: Of the 400 random records returned: Group 1 needs to have 45, Group 2 needs 50, Group 3 needs 35, Group 4, needs 25, Group 5 needs 100, Group 6 needs 5, Group 7 needs 70 and Group 8 needs 70.

And each group is made up of 1-4 different job codes.

Comment: Hm, Why don't you use ORDER BY RAND()

Comment: The NEWID selects the random data just fine, of that 400 each group needs to have a different number represented. SEE EDITS ABOVE

Comment: I looked at that post it didnt answer my question, please see the edits I just made

Comment: What determines a group?  That is, which records belong to Group1, Group2, etc?

Comment: Each group is made up of anywhere from 1-4 different job codes.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just 8 groups you can have 8 *separate* queries (1 for each group) with their own `TOP` number and then `UNION` them all together.

Something like this (You will need to set the correct record amounts to get for each group and correct group codes):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT TOP (100) Business_Unit, GEMSID, First_Name, Last_Name, Region, District, Job_Function,     Email_Address, Job_Group_Code
FROM  dbo.v_TMS_employee_HR
WHERE Job_Group_Code=1 
ORDER BY NEWID())
UNION
...................
UNION
...................
...................
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT TOP (10) Business_Unit, GEMSID, First_Name, Last_Name, Region, District, Job_Function,     Email_Address, Job_Group_Code
FROM  dbo.v_TMS_employee_HR
WHERE Job_Group_Code=8 
ORDER BY NEWID())
```

Since you clarified that there are several job_group_codes in a group you will need to use `WHERE Job_Group_Code IN (1,2,3)` instead.

Comment: Ok I will try this once I get the specific numbers in, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just 8 group and it's one time thing, please try @PM 77-1 suggested. However, I would use `UNION ALL` instead `UNION`.

If you have more group or number of records selected from each group are different, you may try the following way

```
DECLARE @GroupSelect TABLE (Job_Group_Code INT, NumberOfRecord INT)

INSERT INTO @GroupSelect VALUES (1 ,45), (2 ,50)  , ....  -- List all your group and number of records your want select from them

;WITH tbl AS (
SELECT Business_Unit, GEMSID, First_Name, Last_Name, Region, District, Job_Function,     Email_Address, Job_Group_Code
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Job_Group_Code ORDER BY NEWID()) as RowNo
FROM  dbo.v_TMS_employee_HR
)
, numbers ( 
-- if you don't have number table, you may use this. 
 select number + 1 as number from master..spt_values WHERE type = 'P'
)
SELECT t.* 
from tbl t
INNER JOIN @GroupSelect sg  
    ON sg.Job_Group_Code = t.Job_Group_Code
INNER JOIN numbers n 
    ON sg.NumberOfRecord >= n.number
WHERE n.number = t.RowNo
```

Comment: I really do not see the need for `UNION ALL` since different queries will produce results with different `Job_Group_Code` values.

Comment: @PM77-1, yes, it's same result. However, for performance reason, I would use UNION only if I have to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627946/performance-of-union-versus-union-all